# Cross-Game Parties: Which book has final say in the event of a contradiction?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

If a group is using content from multiple game lines (such as *Edge of the Empire* & *Force and Destiny*), which book takes precedence in the event of a contradiction?

For example in EotE Core, the Sixth Sense talent is non-ranked which means that you can only take it once no matter how many of your talent trees contain it.  However, in FaD Core this talent is ranked and can therefore be taken multiple times from different talent trees.

Which book is correct? (Which book takes precedence?)

Comment: Are you asking about that specific example, or are you looking for general guidance?

Comment: While answers referencing that specific example are appreciated, I really would prefer a general rule. It's nice that this particular instance has a developer sanctioned ruling, but I'm more interested in how to resolve a situation where there is not such a ruling.

Answer (score 13):

Sixth Sense (and Superior Reflexes) are both available in **Age of Rebellion** to Quartermasters and Ambassadors as well. There, they are both non-ranked talents.

This has been [confirmed to be an error on the Developer Answered Questions thread](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/108101-ffg-developer-answered-questions/?page=6#comment-1768442).

> **Force and Destiny lists the talent Sixth Sense as Ranked. Edge of the Empire lists it as Unranked. Which is correct?**
>
> It is unranked; the listing of it in Force and Destiny is in error and will be corrected in reprints.
>
> Hope this helps!
>
> Sam Stewart
>
> RPG Manager
>
> Fantasy Flight Games

The **final say** is on the *errata* of each book.

That is because the three (with a fourth coming soon) settings are **cross compatible**. That means that one game takes the previous one into consideration, and not only that, but also the next book. As Edge of the Empire was being written, they already had plans for the other two books. Which means that certain rules were written with that in mind (like the *Force Sensitive Exile*).

So, you can expect that any republishing of a rule, should be compatible with the same rule from the previous book. If not, expect an errata for that book coming up.

This information can be found on the product page of each book, but was already there when Edge of Empire came out ([Source](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire/)):

> Expanding Your Star Wars Universe
>
> Edge of the Empire is the first of three standalone, but fully cross-compatible roleplaying systems. Each introduces a unique dimension of the Star Wars play experience, but the core mechanics are fully interchangeable. Players and GMs will have the option to use these materials separately or combine them as they see fit in order to carve out a unique, custom roleplaying experience.

Comment: Marked down for not addressing the general case in any way.

Comment: You say the errata is the deciding factor, but the errata for *Force and Destiny* has not been released yet to my knowledge (despite the fact that the FaD Core Rulebook was published in 2015). An answer that depends upon errata that does not exist is rather unhelpful.

Comment: I posted a **developer commentary** on the subject, saying "the book is wrong and will be corrected on future prints". But if you want to say that my answer is *unhelpful*, that's fine. This site welcomes you to write your own answer if you think the answers to be wrong or *unhelpful*, or if you come up with the answer by yourself.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the Sixth Sense talent was not reviewed in the current errata (v1.0, 11/10/2017). This answer stand correct, considering the Developer's answer.